# casting an javax.swing.ImageIcon object to org.pdfclown.documents.contents.entities.Image

Tags: java, image, swing, pdf, pdfclown

I'm trying to cast a `javax.swing.ImageIcon` to a `org.pdfclown.documents.contents.entities.Image` so that I can display images in PDF file created by PDF Clown from my Swing application.

I require a ImageIcon because the source image needs to be serializable so that I can store my image as a serialised file as part of a larger, more complex data model.

When I look at the [API for PDF Clown](http://clown.sourceforge.net/docs/api/org/pdfclown/documents/contents/entities/Image.html) I notice `Image` accepts 3 inputs;

1. `String` path. - Wont work because `ImageIcon` doesn't have a Path.
2. `File`. - Wont work because `ImageIcon` doesn't exist on disk.
3. `IInputStream` stream [Reference](http://clown.sourceforge.net/docs/api/org/pdfclown/bytes/IInputStream.html)

This means the only viable method is to use an `IInputStream`. It is an interface so the only way to construct an Object with that type is to use a `FileInputStream` [Reference](http://clown.sourceforge.net/docs/api/org/pdfclown/bytes/FileInputStream.html). This accepts a native Java class of `RandomAccessFile` [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html?is-external=true). This is another dead end as it accepts only `File` and `String`.

The solution then must be to write the `ImageIcon` as an image to disk then read it back. My concern with this is that I need to use a path to store the images before output that the user wont have restricted access to.

Can I do this without writing to disk first?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that API, but it looks like `Buffer` implements `IInputStream`, and accepts a much more flexible variety of constructor arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this class to perform the cast;

```
public class ImageIconToBuffer {
    public static Buffer convert(ImageIcon img) {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = toBufferedImage(img);

            byte[] bytes = toByteArray(image);

            Buffer buffer = new Buffer(bytes);
            return buffer;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static byte[] toByteArray(BufferedImage image) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();            
        JPEGImageEncoder encoder = JPEGCodec.createJPEGEncoder(baos);
        encoder.encode(image);   

        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

    public static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(ImageIcon icon) {
        Image img = icon.getImage();
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null),img.getHeight(null),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D bGr = bi.createGraphics();
        bGr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        bGr.dispose();

        return bi;
    }

}
```